# Tom Apostol Calculus Introduction section 3

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have these theorem

Theorem $1.28$: The set $P$ of positive integers $1, 2, 3, . . .$ is unbounded above

Theorem $1.29$: For every real $x$ there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $n > x$

Theorem $1.30$: If $x > 0$ and if $y$ is an arbitrary real number, there exists a positive integer
$n$ such that $nx > y$

Theorem $1.31$: If three real numbers $a, x$ and $y$ satisfy the inequalities
 $$a\le x  \le a + \frac{y}{n}$$ 
for every integer $n \ge 1$, then $x = a$.

I proved every of these theorem, but, I have a doubt, I can take the same argument of Theorem $1.28$ to prove that Positive Reals are unbounded above (Since is a inductive set) , and then, with that, prove that there exists a positive real $x > n$ being $n$ a positive integer. And the same with the other theorems. Am I wrong at something?

Another question, I see that Theorem $1.31$ have the argument of Exhaustion Method in the introduction section 1, with the theorem $1.30$ I got it, but, I don't really understand why it works, in Exhaustion Method, it says that is contradictory, but, I don't see why (Otherwise, with the Theorem $1.30$ I can see why, but, with my doubt in my first question twisted with this, I'm very confuse, with this and Exhaustion Method last part). I think so hard this, but, I don't understand, if you please can help me, with my first question and understand why is contradictory in Exhaustion Method .

Comment: It isn't true. Part of your hypothesis is that $a < x$.  How could $a = x$?

Comment: My bad, is $a \le x$. Fixed

Comment: The statements in your question are stronger than if you swap the integers for real numbers so they automatically hold. For example all integers are real numbers so if there exists an integer for theorem 1.29 then there exists a real number. I don't understand the second part though sorry